# TargetUpdated does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` that is defined like this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List, ElementName=UI}" x:Name="listBox" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple">            
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid x:Name="grid1" Margin="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                        
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ItemId}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Message, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="TextBlock_TargetUpdated"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The app has a search feature, that allows the user to search for certain text (also a substring) in the list (in column 1, which is bound to 'Message').
The matched substring shall be highlighted as bold or italic.
I'm planning to use the inline feature of the `TextBlock`. Therefore I want to use the `TargetUpdated` callback to parse the contend of the `TextBlock` to insert e.g. Bold() or Italic().

My problem is, that the CallBack function *TextBlock_TargetUpdated* is not called.

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have any binding warning in your Visual Studio console (especially for Message property)?

Comment: @bbougot There are no warnings at all !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, that I was missing a `NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");` in the class that represents the data in the attached list.